# Изменение заливки фигуры MS word с помощью powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

Я новичок в powershell (читай просто "новичок") 
Пытаюсь открыть Word документ, выбрать в нем прямоугольник и поменять в нем цвет.
Может я совсем тупой. Но понять как это сделать не могу.
Достать существующие данные у меня получилось. Но как их изменить?

```
[string]$tmpFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot\test.docx"
[psobject]$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $true
[psobject]$doc = $word.Documents.Open($tmpFilePath)

[psobject]$shape2 = $doc.Shapes.Range("Rectangle 2")
    $shape2.fill.ForeColor.RGB
```

Что теперь сделать, чтобы заменить конкретное значение на желаемое?
Если кто подскажет, буду прыгать от счастья.

Answer (score 0):

Отбой товарищи. Во дундук) Все оказалось просто:

```
[string]$tmpFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot\test.docx"
[psobject]$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $true
[psobject]$doc = $word.Documents.Open($tmpFilePath)

[psobject]$shape2 = $doc.Shapes.Range("Rectangle 2")
    $shape2.fill.ForeColor.RGB = 255
```

Просто присвоить новое значение. Всем спасибо!